# MacBook Air with M1 chip getting hot when I am opening Visual Studio Code, Terminal, Google Chrome

Tags: temperature, apple-silicon

[image]I am a full-stack web developer. I am using MacBook Air with an M1 chip. Last few days I am seeing the laptop getting very hot when I am opening Google Chrome, Visual Studio Code, and Terminal together.

I shut down my laptop for a while to let it cool, but the problem reoccurs frequently. Does anybody have any permanent solution for me?

[image]

Comment: Can you wait til it happens again and then create/add a screenshot of the CPU part of Activity Monitory, showing both the CPU graph at the bottom and the processes needing most CPU?

Comment: After getting @nohillside’s screenshot, can you then collect a spindump in Activity Monitor? (Prediction: We will find that Google Chrome is a bloated monstrosity. Are you able to do your work in Safari instead?)

Comment: Please see my answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431148/windowserver-high-on-macbook-m1-pro/431153#431153 In particular, please follow the procedure I give for collecting a symbolicated spindump during a heavy workload.